# Multi-Targeting and Defined constants around usings

Tags: c#, msbuild

I have a project where I set up the project file as follows:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>netstandard2.0;net472</TargetFrameworks>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <!-- .NET Standard 2.0 references, compilation flags and build options -->
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(TargetFramework)' == 'netstandard2.0'">
    <DefineConstants>NETCORE;</DefineConstants>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup Condition=" '$(TargetFramework)' == 'netstandard2.0'">
  </ItemGroup>

  <!-- .NET 4.7.2 references, compilation flags and build options -->
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(TargetFramework)' == 'net472'">
    <DefineConstants>NETFULL</DefineConstants>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup Condition=" '$(TargetFramework)' == 'net472'">

    <Content Include="3rd Party\SomeThirdParty.dll">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <Pack>true</Pack>
      <PackagePath>lib\$(TargetFramework)</PackagePath>
    </Content>

  </ItemGroup>
```

And am trying to use it in a class like this:

```
using System;
#if NETFULL
using SomeThirdParty.Namespace;
#endif

using mynamespace
{
   public class MyClass
   {
   }
}
```

However I get a compile error for the netstandard2.0 build complaining about
"type of namespace 'SomeThirdParty.Namespace' could not be found"

My understanding is that only the NETFULL build will even see the using statement and try to compile with this.

Can anyone help here?

Comment: I know the site you got this from by the exact same weird spacing in the condition and comment, however, this should work for .net 4.7.2, note another .net framework build will not work, if you believe this to be correct, close app, delete bin and obj directory as things might be out of alignment (just a guess)

Comment: I would like to know why our build box, which deleted everything before downloading and compiling, would be having the same problem? Any thoughts?

Comment: @StephenCossgrove Do you have a two accounts with the same name?